# Disable "auto-scroll" when text select reaches div end?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've added event listeners for mouseDown, mouseUp and mouseMove so the user can click and drag to scroll the list of pills. I would like to leave it `overflow:scroll` for users with touchpads who can scroll horizontally. The problem I'm having is the "auto-scroll" when you reach the end of the element that seems to be part of text selecting. The "auto-scroll" is pushing the scroll in the opposite direction of the click & drag scrolling and it's jumping. Preferably, I would like to leave the text selectable, I just want to disable the auto-scrolling when at the end of the element.

[image: Click&Drag not working]